# Is it safe to attach `authorization bearer {token} header` to protected `client side` axios request?

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

is it safe to attach `authorization bearer {access token} header` to `client side` [ `NEXT JS pages`, NOT in `getServerSideProps`] axios request? will the header `access token` be exposed to the public?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you add to the client-side is exposed to the public.
That's the meaning of client-side.

Nevertheless, it's fine to add an bearer token to the client side, as long as this token is not hard coded (on each request and for each client the same one), but is renewed by site-request (and maybe bind to client-session, requesting ip or stuff like that).